# How to check with watin is element "hidden"

Tags: watin

Is there a way to verify is element hidden or not - using watin.

I don't want to use Jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, there is no concrete way to tell if an individual element is hidden or not in watin.

However, you can recursively check up through the parent tree to see if they contain "display: none" or "visibility: hidden"

This blog gives more detail:
http://blog.coditate.com/2009/07/determining-html-element-visibility.html

You may want to check what method your developers use to hide elements to know if this solution is useful for you.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to work around this by running some jQuery in the browser that reported whether the element was hidden or not:

```
var jsCommand = String.Format("$('#{0}').is(':visible');", fieldId);
var isVisible = ie.Eval(jsCommand) == "true";
```

Comment: Works like a champ.  This is the only way I was able to come up with that works consistently.  Should be pretty easy to make a non-jquery version for people who don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any help, but I recently had to use a hidden text field...

```
public TextField HiddenTitleTextField
{
    get
    {
        return this.Document.TextField(tf => tf.Name == "title" &&
            tf.GetAttributeValue("type") == "hidden");
    }
}
```

HTH!